# What is the set of all premises called?

Tags: logic, terminology

An argument has two parts, the set of all premises, and the conclusion drawn from said premise. Now since there's only 1 conclusion, it would be weird to choose a name for the 'second' part of the argument. However, what is the first part called? I used to think that this was actually called the premise, however that turns out not to be the case. Anyway, what *is* it called? Because I feel like it needs a name.

```
Argument
    Premise 1¯|
    Premise 2 |  <--- What's this called?
    Premise 3_|

    Conclusion
```

What is the part containing premise 1, 2, and 3?

**Edit:**
I just realized that actually, perhaps one conclusion doesn't necessarily need to be drawn, perhaps there can be several conclusions, if so, what is the set of all conclusions called?

Comment: That's the premise, which happens to be the conjunction of three sub-premises.

Comment: Here it says that you can have multiple premises though: http://philosophy.hku.hk/think/sl/full.php

Comment: I'd just say it's the premises. Or the givens. And the conclusions are called the conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

In Model Theory, if you assume $\mathfrak{A}$ to be a model of a language $\mathcal{L}$, you can define a set of sentences $\mathcal{T}$ that is called a theory by letting

$$ \mathcal{T} = \left\{\text{sentence(s) } \sigma \text{ of } \mathcal{L} \text{ such that } \mathfrak{A}  \models \sigma \right\}. $$

In other words, the theory is all sentences of the language which are true under the interpretation of the model.

Then, if you use $\mathcal{T}$ as a set of premises for your proof, then you can call this set of premises a theory. If you want to use a smaller set of premises for your proof, you can reduce $\mathcal{T}$ to a potentially smaller set of sentences by defining $\Sigma$ to be the set of sentences that entails (has as consequences) all sentences in $\mathcal{T}$. This $\Sigma$ is a set of axioms for our theory, and you can also use it as a set of premises for your proof.

Best !

Reference : http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/model_theory.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In natural language arguments, you have finitely many premises. This means that you can put them all together in a single premise that is the conjunction of all the premises.

However, in general, you can treat the premises as a **collection** (which may not be finite). This collection is in first-order logic called the **axioms** of the formal system in question, and we write "$X \vdash φ$" to mean that from the axioms $X$ we can prove $φ$. The collection of all the possible conclusions that can be proven from the axioms $X$ is called the **consequences** of $X$, but I'm not sure whether there's a common notation for it. The collection of all models of $X$ is denoted by "$Md(X)$" and the sentences satisfied by a collection $C$ of models is denoted by "$Th(C)$", and so $Th(Md(X))$ would be the collection of all theorems proven by $X$.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the answer is already in the title of your question: You can simply call it the **set of premises**, or the **premise set**.
This indicates that it is (possibly multiple, but might in principle be the empty set or a singleton set) a set of propositions serving altogether as the premise of the argument, without making any judgement about whether it might be just one single premise or multiple ones to be interpreted as one premise derived by conjunction of several sub-premises.
Similarly, if there are several propositions that are conclusions of the argument, you can simply call it the **set of conclusions**, which is a most neutral term in that it doesn't make any assertions about its elements apart from it being conclusions which is exactly what you want to say.

Comment: But that's not a set in mathematical point of view...

Comment: @skyking It's a set of propositions, so why would it not be a set?

Comment: That's because of details of basic set theory. One draws a distinction between statements (fx propositions) and sets (that can be elements of a set) - this is done to avoid introspection in the theory which could open up for constructing Russel's paradox.

Comment: @skyking Oh okay, I think I understand your point of criticism - you need to decide for a logical type in the first place, because a proposition is obviously not the same as a set of propositions. Is that what you mean by the distinction and the reference to Russel's paradox? If this is what you meant, you are of course right - you would then either need to state that *premise* is meant to denote a proposition, or a set of propositions, which then could not be used interchangeably however.

Comment: My point was that if there are multiple premises, you can indeed collect them in a set - but this was not meant to say that this is of the same logical type as a proposition.

Comment: No, it's the distinction between statements and the set/elements/objects studied in mathematics - and a set can only contain the later. Personally I'd call the premises "the premises" and the conclusion "the conclusion", why complicate things?

Comment: That a proposition could mathematically not be an element of a set is new to me - this is what you do all the time in formal natural language semantics. "Complicating" things to make it clearer what it actually is - because "the conclusion" doesn't really tell much, wasn't that the original problem?

Comment: @skyking In mathematical logic, i.e. the study of logic via mathematics, the propositions of a formal logic are mathematical objects, usually tree-like structures. There is no issue with collecting them into sets. These propositions are (usually) not objects within the formal logic being studied. (Though, for many even modestly powerful formal theories, it's quite possible to *model* these propositions as objects within the formal theory too. It's straightforward to model propositions of ZFC or PA as objects within ZFC or PA.)